# me da Error al manejar el archivo (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hice el codigo pero no entiendo cual es el error y he estado buscando pero no encuentro nada alguien me ayuda?

Comment: Justamente el error indica que el archivo no existe en esa ruta. Verifica si tú ruta está bien escrita y si el archivo está en la ruta que indicas. Si comparas la ruta que indicas en el código con la ruta que te da tu explorador de archivos, notarás que son distintas.

Comment: Buenas, Maximus, si tu sistema operativo es Windows, creo que la ruta correcta es "c:\\user\\Estudiante.txt". La barra \ es un caracter especial como puedes ver en tu propio código cuando representas un tabulador como "\t" así que tienes que "escaparlo" anteponiendo otra barra. Por favor, cuando incluyas código aquí hazlo como texto formateado y no como una imagen. Salud!